# KE in photoelectric effect

Tags: energy, photoelectric-effect

I photoelectric effect when a single photon's energy is absorbed, why don't all get the same Max $KE$. Because for an electron, there can be no loss in heat or any friction and all. Why do most of the particles have $KE \lt KE_{Max}$

Comment: Because it is a scattering experiment "electron +surface" and the solution  is probabilistic as all quantum mechanical framework scatters.

Answer (score 0):

We know that in order for a electron to be ejected from the surface of the metal it must gain energy equal to the work function. The incident photons could have a range of energies:

$$\\E_{\gamma}<\phi \\E_{\gamma}=\phi \\E_{\gamma}>\phi$$

- If the first case is true, no electron will be ejected
- If the second case is true, an electron will be ejected but it will have no kinetic energy
- If the third case is true, an electron will be emitted and it will have kinetic energy equal to $KE=E_{\gamma}-\phi$ (This is what you have denoted as $KE_{max}$)

The reason why not all electrons have kinetic energy equal to the maximum is because not all of the electrons are on the surface of the metal. Electrons deeper within the material require energy to get them  to the surface of the metal thus some energy is lost and now their kinetic energy is less than the maximum.

Comment: Aren't conductors equipotential surfaces? Why would an electron that is free from gaining energy lose energy to move to the surface?

Comment: With respect to a metal, the work function would be the the difference between the vacuum level and the Fermi level. Electrons that absorb the photons at the Fermi level will be the most energetic photons. However, there will also be electrons below the Fermi level which get excited, those will be less energetic.

Comment: Ok, that talks about the energy. I was asking about your claim about being deeper within the conductor.

Comment: Since electrons in a metal are free, when deeper electrons absorb the energy of the photon they get ejected. As they are being ejected they inelastically collide with neighbouring atoms and lose energy thus have a lower kinetic energy.